# Is union a user-defined or derived data type in C language

Tags: c

https://byjus.com/gate/derived-data-types-in-c/ indicates that a union is a Derived Data Type in C

> Types of Derived Data Types in C
>
> The C language supports a few derived data types. These are:
>
> - Arrays – The array basically refers to a sequence (ordered sequence) of a finite number of data items from the same data type
>   sharing one common name.
> - Function – A Function in C refers to a self-contained block of single or multiple statements. It has its own specified name.
> - Pointers – The Pointers in C language refer to some special form of variables that one can use for holding other variables’ addresses.
> - Unions – The unions are very similar to the structures. But here, the memory that we allocate to the largest data type gets reused for
>   all the other types present in the group.
> - Structures – A collection of various different types of data type items that get stored in a contagious type of memory allocation is
>   known as structure in C.

https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/unix/digital/AQTLTBTE/DOCU_034.HTM indicate that a union is a Derived Data Type in C

> 3.4 Derived Types
>
> There are five derived types in C:
>
> - Function types
> - Pointer types
> - Array types
> - Structure types
> - Union types

but  http://www.jnkvv.org/PDF/25042020093559244201357.pdf indicates that union is a User-defined Data Type in C

> C Union
>
> - Union is a user-defined datatype in C programming language.
> - It is a collection of variables of different datatypes in the same memory location.
> - We can define a union with many members, but at a given point of time, only one member can contain a value.
> - Unions can be very handy when you need to talk to peripherals through some memory-mapped registers.

https://www.cplusplus.in/union-in-c/ indicate that a union is a User-defined Data Type in C

#### User defined data type : Union

Like [structures in C](https://www.cplusplus.in/structures-in-c/), union is a user defined [data type](https://www.cplusplus.in/data-types-in-c/).

I search the web but could not get an answer.

I would be grateful if somebody could let me know if a union is a **User-defined** or **Derived** data type in C language.

Comment: You are citing sources that use conflicting terminology.  Some classify unions as "user-defined" data types, and others as "derived" data types.  There is no deep controversy.

Comment: The C language specification defines the term "derived type"to describe array, structure, union, pointer, function, and atomic types, but the relevant English-language sense of "derived" is roughly "defined by the program", and it's not too great a stretch to call that "user-defined", especially for structures and unions.

Comment: Don't you think they can be both, especially since the user derives the data type?

Answer (score 0):

A `union` is both a *'derived type'* — because that is what the [C standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p20) calls it — and a *'user-defined type'* — because `union` types don't exist unless a user defines them.  The standard doesn't include the word/phrase 'user-defined' (with or without a hyphen).

Both terms are reasonable — and both apply to `union` types.  They are not mutually exclusive.

For comparison, read the whole section of the standard on 'types' that I linked to.  See how many different ways types are classified.  Every built-in type is classified in a number of non-exclusive ways.